# how to get double records in SharePoint CAML query?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, caml

I've created a View and did group by on a field and then did count on that field. It gives me all records and the total counts. I want to show only records which are greater than 1.... where to put this Greater than in the code ?

I created the view and I opened the view in SharePoint designer and my code looks like this now?  I want to put somewhere **count(Commitment_x0020_Reference) > 1**

```
<XmlDefinition>
<View Name="{358474DF-DB87-423E-A795-6C361A33655F}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Double SI" Url="/networks/SCP/Lists/Contracts and Studies/Double SI.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" >
    <Query>
        <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="500">
            <FieldRef Name="Commitment_x0020_Reference"/>
        </GroupBy>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Date_x0020_of_x0020_Reception" Ascending="FALSE"/>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/>
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Edit"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Type_x0020_of_x0020_Procedures"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Unit"/><FieldRef Name="Reference"/><FieldRef Name="Title1"/><FieldRef Name="_x0039_i_x002d_Com_x0020_L2_x002"/><FieldRef Name="Modified"/><FieldRef Name="Editor"/><FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">50</RowLimit>
    <Aggregations Value="On">
        <FieldRef Name="Commitment_x0020_Reference" Type="COUNT"/>
    </Aggregations>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. Querying by the sum of grouped results is not possible with a single CAML query.

Alternate options would be to perform post-processing on the results, so the query returns all records, then you remove the unwanted records on the client side, such as with JavaScript; or you could perform multiple queries in sequence to retrieve every possible value for `Commitment_x0020_Reference`, then perform multiple queries using those values to retrieve and count the number of results for each `Commitment_x0020_Reference` value.

Neither of those options is very straightforward to implement from the SharePoint Designer GUI, and may warrant a separate Stack Overflow question depending on your approach.